# Destroy gameobject with raycast RPC

Tags: c#, multiplayer, raycasting, destroy, photon

Im trying to destroy a gameobject when detect by specific player with raycast.

Its need to be done with RPC - the Instansate allso not happened with PhotonNetwork.

this is the code line :

```html
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            Ray ray = _camController.PlayerCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            // Casts the ray and get the first game object hit
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
            {

                if (hit.collider.tag == "test")
                {
                   Destroy(hit.transform.parent.gameObject);
                    Debug.Log("Hit");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I do the line for Destroy(hit.transform.parent.gameObject); In RPC if I cant send RaycastHit in RPC method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PhotonView that is attached to the hit object.

```
if (hit.collider.tag == "test")
{
    Debug.Log("Hit");

    // Use GetComponentInParent depending on your object hierachy/collider setup..
    //
    var photonView = hit.collider.GetComponent<PhotonView>(); 
    if (photonView)
    {
        Debug.Log("Sending DestroyTest RPC");
        photonView.RPC("DestroyTest", RPCTarget.All);
    }
}
```

and on the script attached to the object you hit:

```
[PunRPC]
private void DestroyTest()
{
    Debug.Log("DestroyTest()");
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```